# row minus row within different list R

Tags: r

How can I calculate the difference between different rows within different list?
and different list have different dimensions.
I use the code as follows

```
names(ri1)
[1] "Sedol" "code"  "ri"    "date"
ri1<-ri1[order(ri1$Sedol,ri1$date),]
sri<-split(ri1,ri1$Sedol)
ri1$r<-as.vector(sapply(seq_along(sri), function(x) diff(c(0, sri[[x]][,3]))))
```

however it shows the result

```
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "r", value = list(c(100, 0.00790000000000646,  : 
replacement has 1485 rows, data has 4687655"
```

for example

I have three lists

1. ```
   date  ri
   1990  1
   1991  2
   1992  3
   ```
2. ```
   date  ri
   1990  1
   1991  2
   1992  3
   1993  4
   ```
3. ```
   date  ri
   1990  1
   1991  2
   ```

I want the results like

1. ```
   date  ri  r
   1990  1   0%
   1991  2   100%
   1992  3   100%
   ```
2. ```
   date  ri  r
   1990  1   0%
   1991  2   100%
   1992  3   100%
   1993  4   100%
   ```
3. ```
   date  ri   r
   1990  1    0%
   1991  2    100%
   ```

notice: `r= r(t+1)/r(t)-1`

Comment: are you sure about your r formula? it don't give the result

Comment: You could have made your example reproducible by providing `ri1` using `dput`. Please refer to [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of `head` and `tail` as follows:

```
r.fun <- function(ri) c(0, tail(ri, -1) / head(ri, -1) - 1)
lapply(sri1, transform, r = r.fun(ri))
```

If your goal is to recombine (`rbind`) your data afterwards, then know that you can split/apply/combine everything within a single call to `ave` from the base package, or `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
transform(ri1, r = ave(ri, Sedol, FUN = r.fun))
```

or

```
library(plyr)
ddply(ri1, "Sedol", transform, r = r.fun(ri))
```

*Edit:* If you want the output to be in XX% as in your example, replace `r.fun` with:

```
r.fun <- function(ri) paste0(round(100 * c(0, tail(ri, -1) / head(ri, -1) - 1)), "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using diff and lapply you can get something like

```
# I generate some data
  dat1 <- data.frame(date = seq(1990,1999,length.out=5),ri = seq(1,10,length.out=5))
  dat2 <- data.frame(date = seq(1990,1999,length.out=5),ri=seq(1,5,length.out=5))
# I put the data.frame in a list 
  ll <- list(dat1,dat2)
 # I use lapply:
  ll <- lapply(ll,function(dat){
    # I apply the formula you give in a vector version
    # maybe you need only diff in percent?
    dat$r <- round(c(0,diff(dat$ri))/dat$ri*100)
    dat
  })
ll
[[1]]
     date    ri  r
1 1990.00  1.00  0
2 1992.25  3.25 69
3 1994.50  5.50 41
4 1996.75  7.75 29
5 1999.00 10.00 22

[[2]]
     date ri  r
1 1990.00  1  0
2 1992.25  2 50
3 1994.50  3 33
4 1996.75  4 25
5 1999.00  5 20
```